# Method open of object workbooks failed error

Tags: vba, excel

When Im executing this code i'm getting an error [Run-time error '1004': Method 'Open' of object 'Workbooks' failed.

I read online that this might be an error with the actual file so I also tried using "IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True" to allow the file to repair itself but that didn't work either. Any suggestions on how to get around this?

```
Sub BlueFieldImport()

Dim mywb As Workbook
Set mywb = ThisWorkbook
Dim filepath As String, fp As String
Dim mymonth As String

mymonth = Sheets("Data_Staging").Range("A38").Value

filepath = FindFile("C:\Book1.xls")

Dim BlueFieldsWB As Workbook
Set BlueFieldsWB = Workbooks.Open(filepath, , ReadOnly:=True)
```

Comment: What does `FindFile` do? i.e. is `filePath` valid when it's passed to `Workbooks.Open`? Also, you're using named parameters, remove that empty positional parameter.

Comment: Depending on your situation, you could use the `Add()` method instead of `Open()` which would still open the file if it was currently open somewhere else (if that's the problem). `Add()` has a template argument.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using variable, just pass the string containing the path.

What is the logic behind function to find the file if you pass it direct path anyway?